# php version from phpinfo different from installed php when using vagrant/chef/nginx

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile

ok so I'm installing the cookbooks for php and php-fpm using vagrant

see https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php and
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php-fpm

Here is part of my Vagrantfile

```
      chef.add_recipe "php::source"
      chef.add_recipe "php-fpm"
      chef.add_recipe "nginx"
      :php => {
        :version => "5.6.13"
      },
```

and also

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
```

here's part of nginx configuration

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm-www.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
```

but then when I visit phpinfo.php which contains phpinfo() function, it would output PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25

whereas when I do php -v it outputs PHP 5.6.13

I want to use PHP 5.6.13....how can I configure vagrant so that it uses PHP 5.6.13 for the actual php script served by the web server?

Comment: Check the cookbook you're using, php-fpm install by default the package version, see https://github.com/yevgenko/cookbook-php-fpm/blob/master/recipes/install.rb#L36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using php-fpm so the version of the `php` binary is moot. What matters is the version that fpm is set up to use. AFAIK this is done at compile time for fpm itself so you would probably need to find newer packages for that.